# Direct access to site when log in

Tags: login

Is possible to have a direct access to the site when log in?
I mean, when you log in, you access to the WP editor page. I want that user of my site will directly forwarded to the site.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want them to be redirected to the *Articles* dashboard page? Or to the *Pages* dashboard page? Or to altogether create a new article or page?

Comment: No. I want that the homepage of the site is shown.

Answer (score 3):

That is pretty straight forward, you use the `login_redirect` filter hook which is there for exactly this case.

You would add something like this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function home_login_redirect( $redirect ){

    // Check if user is administrator; you probably want to redirect
    // him to the dashboard, don't you?
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) return $redirect;
    else return home_url();

}

add_filter("login_redirect", "home_login_redirect");
```

Comment: thank you very much! but I cannot access to functions.php (actually, I cannot access to the file system which hosts the site). I can only execute php code by using some suitable plugin.

Comment: If you have administrator permissions you can always access the `functions.php` file through the dashboard. Just go to **Appearance > Editor** from there, on the right side, you will see the `functions.php`.

Comment: At the end of editor page, I have the following: "You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See the Codex for more information."

Comment: And did you read the Codex for more information? Anyhow, are you sure you cannot access the host? That's very weird. If so, you are basically asking a plugin recommendation, which is off-topic on this site. Also, if really so, your question answers itself with a simple Google search: here's the first match http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-login-redirect/

Comment: The site is hosted by the server of my department. Their policies does not allow access to the filesystem to external people.